# Can I add style using class="xyz" to GWT CellList rendering?

Tags: java, css, gwt

If I do this

```
sb.appendHtmlConstant("<div class=\"" + CELL_RESOURCES.style().title() + "\">");
```

in the CellList render method then my generated HTML ends up looking like

```
<div class="title">Wow!</div>
```

but the CSS that is generated does not include the "title" class/selector and so no CSS gets applied.

Is there a way of applying CSS styling to parts of the CellList rendering?

Comment: Have you tried putting the class title in your projects _main_ CSS file? (The one with the same name as the main html file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you call `CELL_RESOURCES.style().ensureInjected();` somewhere in your code (preferable as soon as possible in you startup code)? to make sure the css is actually injected?

Comment: That's what I have missed - thanks. I was caught out because I am overriding the list styling (which I don't need to inject) as well as defining my own style for the cell contents (which I do need to inject).